# Can not get the availability status for NON-contact Lync users

Tags: lync

Our solution relays messages that come into our software to the user via Lync.  If the user is not available in Lync then we queue the message for delivery once the user becomes 'Available' again in Lync.  I have created a subsription based on ContactInformationType.Availability to all the contacts (112) and have wired up an eventhandler for the the contact.ContactInformationChanged event which gets raised when a contact's availability has changed.

My code for subscribing looks like this,

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes to contacts.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="group">List of Lync contacts.</param>
    void SubscribeToContacts(List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Total Contacts: " + contacts.Count.ToString());

        foreach (var contact in contacts)
            contact.ContactInformationChanged += new EventHandler<ContactInformationChangedEventArgs>(Contact_ContactInformationChanged);

        contactSubscription = contactManager.CreateSubscription();

        //Choose the types of presence changes to listen for
        var contactInformationTypes = new List<ContactInformationType>() { ContactInformationType.Availability };

        contactSubscription.Subscribe(ContactSubscriptionRefreshRate.High, contactInformationTypes);

        //contactSubscription.AddContacts(contacts);
        foreach (var item in contacts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Uri);
            contactSubscription.AddContact(item);

            Console.WriteLine(item.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability).ToString());
        }
    }
```

The issue I'm encountering is that if the user is not a contact in my list or has never been a part of a search then that user's presense status is always 'None' or (0), so although the user may be online and available in Lync I can 'see' that they are.  I have a seen a few places online which says this should work but I just can't seem to get it too.  Also, it appears that the contact.ContactInformationChanged event for that type of user is not raised either.

I should mention that I'm using the Lync SDK and the Online Service via Office 365.

I've been struggling with this for far too long now for something that I think should work as I have it.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Troy

Comment: My experience is that the contact.ContactInformationChanged event may get fired once initially, but I've never gotten it to reliably respond when the contact changes their presence in Lync.  I've resorted to just polling the contacts that I need to track every X seconds, with contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.Availability)

Answer (score 0):

Since the Non-Lync Contacts are not Accessing the App through Lync Server or you may say, **They are not Using Lync**, The Presence os such IDs will be Unknown to Lync client.